# Adding values from a single sql field into an array

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have a multiple location system with users assigned to a location. During then login they choose if their location (database) in which they wish to login and if the location chosen equals their assigned location, then they will be able to continue. If not, an error is shown.  This all works fine but I have been given a new situation - multiple locations per user.

In my SQL table I have a column called `location` which contains one location. If I add another location separated by a comma is there a way to store the values (ie: location1, location 2) into an array once I have selected the column when the user logs in.

Example of the sql I would be using...

```
SELECT location FROM users WHERE userid = 25
```

So the location row would technically have two values in here. 
Once I have that in an array I can use the `inarray()` function to do my checks.

Comment: If each user has multiple locations, why not put them in a separate table? For example, `users_locations` table with the `id, user_id, location` fields.

Comment: You would lose referential integrity if you had many singular locations that shouldn't be repeated, You could change the location assignment to a ManyToMany association table. Named `users_locations` which would store the user id and location id. Then you would perform a `join` like: `SELECT l.name FROM users_locations AS ul JOIN locations AS l ON l.id = ul.location WHERE ul.user = 25` This would produce all of the locations where the user has been assigned.

Comment: Simple. Don't add another location separated by a comma. See normalisation.

Comment: I have implemented the below answer but have run into problems as I need to add and remove the locations when needed now.  I can easily add the location using CONCAT_WS but removing it is a different story.  I will look into creating a new table for locations to make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED
I created a new table to hold the userID & location.  Select all locations by userid into an array and is the `inarray()` function to carry out my checks.
Allowed for easy adding and removal of locations when needed.
Thanks for the back and forward with the ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode()` to turn string to array, with a needle. In your case it would be `,`

```
$pizza  = "piece1,piece2,piece3,piece4,piece5,piece6";
$pieces = explode(",", $pizza);
```